# Search results orderby category or taxonomy ? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

How to sort wordpress results by category or taxonomy?

I have this code:

```
function ordenarResultados($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) { return; }
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        $query->set('orderby', 'title');
    }
}add_action('pre_get_posts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\ordenarResultados');
```

There is some way to bring the results ordered by custom category ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little unclear.

Is the question "how do you limit search results by category?"

Possibly you want to set a category. I believe this would work

```
$query->set('cat', 123);
```

Or you may want a tax query

```
$taxquery = array(
            'relation'=>'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'custom_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' =>  array(123) ,
                )
            );
$query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);
```